# How can i align <li> and logo<img> next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to align it with the logo. I'm trying to use padding but it won't work and even float maybe I would change the container size for it to work. Btw you won't be able to see the image and the li option due to overflow not allowing links so I have  attached an image for more convenience
if possible maybe even tell some tips to be better in HTML

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFpXX.png)

```css
header {
    height: 600px;
    background-image:urlenter code here;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .header-container {
    height: 1240px;
    width: 1240px;
    padding-left: 3%;
  }
  
  .header-logo{
      height: 150px;
      width: 450px;


  }
  img.logo{
      width: 400px;
      height: 150px;
  }
  nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    }
  
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  nav ul li a {
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: #111111;
  }
  
  nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f22222;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

    <title>Katalyst Incorporation LLC.</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="up">
        <div class="header-container">
            <nav>
                <div class="header-logo">
                    <img class="logo" src="./img/katalyst incorporation logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe it will help you please check : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_navbar_on_image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aligning an image next to an unordered list horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814885/aligning-an-image-next-to-an-unordered-list-horizontally)

Comment: And another [putting text and images on same line within a list item - html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998947/putting-text-and-images-on-same-line-within-a-list-item-html-css) and another [Align image and list on same line in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265108/align-image-and-list-on-same-line-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make logo and menu in a line, you should add "float: left" style to your div. So your style will be this:

```css
.header-logo {
    height: 150px;
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
}
```

Then if you want change your menu vertical align you can add "margin-top: px" to your ul like this:

```css
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As ***logo div*** and `ul` are children of same parent,

you can make their parent i.e `<nav>` as `display: flex` to align it's children in a flex-row

**[Learn More on FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)**

```
nav {
 display: flex;
}
```

```css
header {
  height: 600px;
  background-image: urlenter code here;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-container {
  height: 1240px;
  width: 1240px;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 450px;
}

img.logo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  /* color: #ffffff; */
  color: #000; /* changing this so that you can see color */
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f22222;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

  <title>Katalyst Incorporation LLC.</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="up">
    <div class="header-container">
      <nav>
        <div class="header-logo">
          <img class="logo" src="./img/katalyst incorporation logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I have changed the font color, so that you can see it working.